# Reference definition from ts-check JS file

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc

I have a mixed TS/JS project - ultimately we'll go full TS, but that's a long way away for now.

In the meantime we're using `// @ts-check` derectives in JS files and `<script>` tags, which are pretty powerful.

I want to reference some of the TS definitions in the JS files, something like this:

```
// @ts-check
/// <reference path="MyInterface.d.ts" />

/** @type {MyInterface}  */
let x = ...
```

Only this doesn't work - the TS type checking (and VS2017's intellisense) thinks `x` is `any`.

I want intellisense for the type definition on `x` and warnings when `x.propName` is called but `MyInterface` doesn't have `propName`.

I know that I could replace `<reference path="MyInterface.d.ts" />` with a JS doc `@typedef`, but I have a *lot* of definition files and don't want definitions duplicated.

Is there any way to make `@ts-check` reference a `.d.ts` file?

Comment: Do you by any chance have an import in your definition file? [That requires some extra declarations.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18655)

Comment: @Aankhen yes, we're using ES6 `import` extensively in the TS derective files, but not in the JS. I'll give that a try.

Comment: @Aankhen tried that - it doesn't work. We don't want every `.d.ts` definition to become global, each contains specific `export` and `export default` derectives - in the `@ts-check` references the class is always the default, so in `MyInterface.d.ts` we have both `export interface MyInterface` and `export default MyInterface`, so that `import { MyInterface } ...` or `import MyInterface ...` both work.

Comment: Gotcha. No other ideas, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [official recommendation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14377#issuecomment-371964569) is to use import types:

```
// @ts-check

/** @type {import("./MyInterface").MyInterface} */
let x = ...;
```

Alternatively, you can use `@typedef` to assign a name to the imported type:

```
// @ts-check

/** @typedef {import("./MyInterface").MyInterface} MyInterface

/** @type {MyInterface} */
let x = ...;
```

Comment: That works, and is also the first time I've come across that syntax for JSDoc `@type` derectives (it looks like an ES6 dynamic `import` without the `await`). Someone really needs to add that to some documentation somewhere.